# How to convert JavaScript comma separated object to array of name value pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There is a JavaScript object:

`{"Due_Date__c":"2020-08-26","Status__c":""}`

How can it be converted into an array of name value pairs like so:

```
[
   { 
     name: "Due_Date__c",
     value: "2020-08-26"
   },
   { 
     name: "Status__c",
     value: ""
   },
]
```

Comment: plenty of answers on SO for how to do that already, do [a bit of searching first](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.entries to convert the object into an array of key and value pairs. You can then map that to the object.

```js
var obj = {
  "Due_Date__c": "2020-08-26",
  "Status__c": ""
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the keys to an array.

```js
const nameValue = obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((results, key) => {
  results.push({ name: key, value: obj[key] });
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(nameValue({"Due_Date__c":"2020-08-26","Status__c":""}));
```

Comment: Thank you, Adrian! Exactly what I was looking for!